# Why aren't my images showing up on my github page?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I've setup a github page, but my images are not loading.
[The site](http://the4dpatrick.github.io/aboutmatthew/) and
[The Site's Repo](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/aboutmatthew/tree/gh-pages)

I saw this question [Images in github pages and relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141612/images-in-github-pages-and-relative-links) where it said that GitHub is run on Linux servers, thus case-sensitive. I can checked that the href directory is the same case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files with underscores are treated specially by GitHub pages.  You need to add a .nojekyll file in the root path, to turn off jekyll.

Look at [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing) for details

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try removing the tailing slashes in your `<img>`-tags (and all the others that have it) as this violates the HTML 5 specification.

Comment: Thanks took the / away from tags in the index.html, but that didn't do anything. I may have messed up the vertical-align now somehow because there is a gap with the main image and the thumbnails.