# Pictures not showing up in site hosted by GitHub

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, picasa

I have a website hosted by Github and I am having issues with displaying pictures. I recently tried to upload new pictures but despite the path being right, the page fails to load the images and gives a 404 error in the source as it tries to find the path. Here is the repo of my site: https://github.com/jeanturban/jeanturban.github.io

I think it might have something to do with Picasa as when I download a picture from the internet and update the path accordingly it works fine. But when I try to use pictures from my computer, or if I try to export from Picasa to my "img" folder, then it breaks. Perhaps Picasa is making a hidden folder upon exporting the pictures that is not being uploaded? Anyone have any insight on this? Or a workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141612/images-in-github-pages-and-relative-links

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your images are not loading due to the wrong file extension. You are trying to load "http://jeanturban.com/img/Current/light1.jpg" when it should be "http://jeanturban.com/img/Current/light1.JPG" -- notice the capital JPG at the end.

Comment: damn that's simple -- didn't think the case in the file extension actually mattered. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was my images where in a `.attachments` folder (coming from Azure DevOps) and I guess GitHub pages skipped hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but image case was not problem.

What fixed it was shortening image file name from 26 characters with three underscores to 16 characters and one underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the path for where my media files were stored for my case:

before my file setup was:

```
-myusername.github.io
-->index.html
-->index.css
->media
-->myImage.jpg
```

after I changed it to the setup below, it worked:

```
I had to change it to this: 
->myusername.github.io
-->index.html
-->index.css
-->media
--->myImage.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd converted my WordPress site to a static site via HTTrack, it had a 'srcset' attribute which was causing the issue. I simply deleted that attribute and it's values (which were original site urls) and update my gh-pages repo and the images showed up like charm.