# Images not displaying in Github Pages?

Tags: html, image, github, github-pages

I added a project site to my Github project. But some photos are not displaying in the site.

Img code:

```
<img src="img/screenshot2.PNG" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
```

folder structure (img is a folder):

```
img
    Screenshot2.png
index.html
```

I tried with `.png` and `.PNG` (some earlier SO answers suggested it) and none of them work

Any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196788/pictures-not-showing-up-in-site-hosted-by-github

Comment: >> Make sure to fully reload the page with **`Ctrl` + `R`**

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it.

If anyone has the same problem.

GitHub Pages are case sensitive. Not only for folders, but also for image names.

Comment: In my case, it worked after small delay. I assume that github hosting server took some time to update files.

Answer (score 20):

yes, i have the same problem
There are two most powerful ways to solve it

1. pay attention to the writing of image extensions, because on github pages `Images.png` is different from `images.png`
2. if in your code you write src on image like this `src="/images/images.png"` just remove / at the beginning of the section, and it will solve your problem.

Comment: I removed the '/' at the beginning, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 14):

Adding my two cents for googlers: Git Pages seem to ignore the directories starting with underscore, so make sure you don't have `<a href="_images/whatever.jpg">`.

Comment: +1 by the time I scrolled past all the comments from those learning the web is case-sensitive I had started to wonder if the reason github pages can't find an image was because of that underscore in my path.

Comment: If you are not using Jekyll, you can add the `.nojekyllfile` so that underscore images are recognised.

See reference here: https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/

Answer (score 12):

As @dnivog mentioned, GitHub's servers take a little time to update files.

If nothing of the above addresses your situation, just check back in a little while. ⏳

Answer (score 10):

Write what you see.

It is `Screenshot2.png`. With a lower-case `png` and a capital `S` at the start.

Answer (score 7):

While hosting a website on Github,I faced the same issue.The image file was saved as an .jpg extension on my local(in small letters) and It was working fine.  I pushed the same to github. That did not work.

I had to change the extension to .JPG (in caps)since it was the original extension of the image.Github Pages are case sensitive to the name of the files being uploaded.

Comment: This was my fix as well. I renamed everything using snake-case, and lowercase, to avoid any potential unknowns. Images are now working.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem today. I solved it by:

- Double-check the `Case Sensitive` of the images (i.e. `Screenshot.png` isn't the same as `Screenshot.PNG` or even `screenshot.png`)
- Double-check the `PATH` of the image. For me; It was `../img/myImg.jpg`, and I changed it to `./img/myImg.jpg` to point to the current directory of the project

After fixing the 2 mentioned issue above, it worked fine... Hope it help you get unstuck!

Comment: I had the same issue: a stray "../" which worked locally because I already was on root level, but removed the repo name on GH pages.

Answer (score 6):

I tried using both JPG or jpg but it didn't work.

I tried below steps and it worked fine.

Try using the complete path. Let's say your image is inside repo-name/img/pic.jpg. Then use https://username.github.io/repo-name/img/pic.jpg instead of just /img/pic.jpg.

Answer (score 6):

for anyone still scrolling through the answers:
do the following steps:

0. Make sure the image has actually been uploaded on your remote. On your main repo page , click on the name of the image, and see if it opens: if yes continue to next step
1. Load the site with "Github pages"
2. Open up inspect element (DevTools) , go to the html element in your .html file OR your CSS Style where you have defined your `src`
3. Here try out all the various solutions that people have described above [**what worked for me:** I added `./`to the beginning of my `src` => `./name-image`
4. whichever solution works, make that change in your local html or CSS and push to github.

Answer (score 4):

I had a folder on my laptop named "assets", but when I pushed to Github it became "Assets". I had to change it in my HTML so I could view the images on the Github page

The repo on my laptop:
[image: The repo on my laptop]

The repo on GitHub:
[image: The repo on Github]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, except I used git-lfs to manage the images. GitHub Pages doesn't support LFS, which will prevent the image from being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem, GitHub Pages appears to be case-sensitive for images, and I wrote .JPG instead of .jpg, once I changed my image extension to be lowercase it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has this problem while using jekyll to build a github site, there's yet another variation on this problem. It's a variation of the several answers above to prepend '.' or '..' on the image path in regular html. In the case of jekyll, which renders markdown source files, what should be prepended is `{{site.baseurl}}`, where `baseurl` is provided in the jekyll config file and is the root directory of the github repo. In other words:

```
![image 1](/images/image1.png "Image 1")
```

will render locally,

```
![image 1](./images/image1.png "Image 1")
```

will render on github pages as per the several answers above, and

```
![image 1]({{site.baseurl}}/images/image1.png "Image 1")
```

will render both locally and on github pages, which is the best way to do it with jekyll since all the coding of the site can be done locally in advance of pushing to github.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled quite a while until I saw one post by Elharony: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5560399/elharony 
talking about case sensitivity. It turned out Jupyter notebook is case insensitive for image files, but GitHub is. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are importing file into your JS file and using relative path.
Remember to have the relative path from the HTML file and not from JS file as it'll finally compile into the HTML file only.

Answer (score 2):

my original <img src="images/walnut.png" change to <img src="/blob/main/images/walnut.png"

Will work on github hosting pages

Answer (score 1):

You can try by putting the "image link address" from the github repository, in the 'src' attribute of the 'img' tag of the HTML code of your file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this answer can not solve the question, already he use th `src` in his image tag and the problem still remains, please read question more carefully and then try to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with GitHub pages:

instead of `../img/image.png`, I wrote `../img/image.PNG` and now it works fine.
I know this is not a solution but somehow worked for me.

Just in case if someone encounters this error!

Comment: Changing .png to .PNG wouldn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue In my case the issue was of `/`

`<img src="/Images/shared/desktop/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo" />`

I was using this for my Image in `html` in local machine it was working fine
but in `github` its not displaying image

but when I removed `/` from  the `path` it worked

`<img src="Images/shared/desktop/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo" />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I changed 'img' folder to 'image', then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I changed /image.png to image.png and it helped.

(when pointing to an image on GitHub pages the file doesn't need the "/" if it's in the same file as the html or the file that it's referencing it!)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was having the images in LFS, but not checking out LFS files in my Github actions workflow that deploys to pages.

In your workflow, you need to enable LFS in your checkout step.

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    lfs: true
```

Notice the `lfs: true` configuration.

Source: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50337#discussioncomment-5349819

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LFS together with GitHub Pages and Actions, deployment of images and other assets isn't supported out of the box. A workaround could be to update `actions/checkout` in your deployment pipeline:

```
- name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      lfs: true
```

Fix example [here](https://github.com/jakob-bagterp/colorist-for-python/blob/bfcbfc3697bbf4108f748e6afbbd1c1a9c7f364a/.github/workflows/docs.yml#L15-L17).

Reference: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50337#discussioncomment-5349819

Answer (score 0):

Have to add my 2 cents here:

1. Some images might be loading because they are less than 10 Kb and Babel will load them as data URLs instead of relative paths.
2. Make sure that your 'homepage' is configured correctly in the package.json file. When you deploy via gh-pages, your 'homepage' should be set to the link for the website that Github generates.

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Images weren't showing up in deployed webapp.
The problem was my images were stored in the src folder.
The solution was to move the images to public folder.

[image]

Now I referenced the image as:

```
<img className="hero-img" src="images/landing.png" alt="" />
```

The images started showing up in the deployed as well