# Images not showing up on GitHub

Tags: github

Im trying to publish a challenge on frontend mentor using Git Hub.
When i try to use the live url, images dont show up.
Ive tried PNG, paths and some more things i saw on the Internet but ,for now, nothing has worked.
Live Url:https://pires29.github.io/First-Project/
GitHub Page:https://github.com/Pires29/First-Project.git
(Could put the code in here)
img src="image-qr-code.PNG"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not displaying in Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468951/images-not-displaying-in-github-pages). Just tried this on your page and it works. You need to replace `PNG` with `png`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path.
Your images should be on the public file and your path must looks like `/<imagesFile>/image.png`