# Images do not load on live url

Tags: html, css

i have a problem that the images are loaded normally while im building something with HTML and CSS, but when I make a repo on GitHub and make a live url the images are not loading in this live url.
I have faced this problem multiple of times till now, and i still have no idea where is the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjSDh.png)

Comment: If you use relative urls, you should set [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). That would explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not displaying in Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468951/images-not-displaying-in-github-pages)