# Images are not loading in GitHub pages hosted from docs directory

Tags: html, angular, image, github, github-pages

My images are not loading in GitHub pages and my base `href` in `/docs/index.html` is "/SindhuApp/

I am deploying from `/docs` in GitHub.

[This is the folder structure in GitHub pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIQrI.png)
[I am deploying from /docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V58H.png)

And this is from the file `src/app/login/login.component.html`:

```html
<div>
<p class="Anime"><img src="src/assets/angular5.png" alt="Angular Image" style="height: 70px; width:80px;" >
    <img src="docs/assets/ts.png" alt="TS Image" style="height: 70px; width:70px"> 
    <img src="docs/assets/html.png" alt="HTML Image" style="height: 75px; width:75px">
    <img src="docs/assets/css.png" alt="CSS Image" style="height: 75px; width:75px">
    <img src="docs/assets/material.png" alt="Material Image" style="height: 65px; width:70px"></p>
</div>
```

I am unable to see the images and this is my portfolio project. I tried all the solutions in stack overflow but none is working for me. But all the pages are loading properly only except images.

Comment: If you're hosting from `docs/`, file paths should be relative to `docs/` not the repo root (and you won't have access to files outside of `docs/`, like, for example, `src/`).

Comment: Thanks Henry for reply,  I added src/ path for testing purpose only. docs/ path images are not loading @HenryWoody

Answer (score 0):

Since your site is hosted from the `docs/` directory, your import paths need to reflect this. Currently the import paths are configured relative to the repository root rather than the `docs/` directory.

The fix for this is quite simple in this case, you just need to remove the `docs/` prefix from your import paths, like this:

```html
<div>
<p class="Anime"><img src="assets/angular5.png" alt="Angular Image" style="height: 70px; width:80px;" >
    <img src="assets/ts.png" alt="TS Image" style="height: 70px; width:70px"> 
    <img src="assets/html.png" alt="HTML Image" style="height: 75px; width:75px">
    <img src="assets/css.png" alt="CSS Image" style="height: 75px; width:75px">
    <img src="assets/material.png" alt="Material Image" style="height: 65px; width:70px"></p>
</div>
```

Keep in mind also that `docs/` will be the root directory when hosted so you cannot access siblings of `docs/` (e.g. `src/`), even with import paths that reflect the correct location (e.g. `../src/` will not work). If you need access to other resources, they will need to be placed in `docs/` as well.

You might run into difficulty because the import paths need to be different for development and deployment. One way you can handle this is by keeping your images within the `src/` directory and copying them over to `docs/` as part of your build process. You might want to check out the package [angular-cli-ghpages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) to help with the build and deployment.

---

Another thing to note is that import paths with GitHub Pages are case-sensitive as discussed here: [Images not displaying in Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41468951/8068625).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution @Henry Woody, I actually tried another solution before your answer as my live portfolio project looks awful without images - Solution: like using RAW GitHub images.