# Image not shown on site hosted by GitHub

Tags: html, css, image, web, github

I finally managed to upload my website on GitHub but two of my images are not shown.
On VS Code i don't have any problems coming up.

Here's a link to my website - https://micheellee.github.io/rustysphotoblog/index.html

And a link to my github profile-
https://github.com/Micheellee/rustysphotoblog

Comment: Looks like the URL is case sensitive. If you navigate to `https://micheellee.github.io/rustysphotoblog/Photos/Backyard/BYC.png` you will get a 404 but have the `PNG` in uppercase and everything works as expected `https://micheellee.github.io/rustysphotoblog/Photos/Backyard/BYC.PNG`

Comment: Well observed - it's always likely to be a URL problem but I couldn't find it for the life of me - as a side note in the source code the image hyperlinks  have a lowercase `.png` more than 2 times, which is ....strange

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Any idea why or how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Pictures not showing up in site hosted by GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196788/pictures-not-showing-up-in-site-hosted-by-github) or [Images not displaying in Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468951/images-not-displaying-in-github-pages)