# Images not appearing in Github webpage

Tags: html, image, github-pages

Problem seems clear by the title. :-(
**My code**:

```
<img src="/images/bgm.png">
```

**Folder's tree**:

- index.html

- Images

  - bgm.png

**Solutions that I tried**:

- [Images in github pages and relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141612/images-in-github-pages-and-relative-links)
- [Pictures not showing up in site hosted by GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196788/pictures-not-showing-up-in-site-hosted-by-github)
- [Images not displaying in Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468951/images-not-displaying-in-github-pages)

**My github page**:

- [Login Form Demo](https://neutralme.github.io/login/)

**Code for the page**:

- [Github](https://github.com/neutralme/login)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path to your images should be "images/filename" instead of "../images/filename"

**Index.html** and **images** are in the same directory so for accessing something in the same directory you dont need to add "." or ".."