# How do you use github?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am absolutely struggling on how to use github. I think I know the basic of uploading an index.html and style.css file but having my images upload I am struggling. When I host my website from my local file on to google chrome it works perfectly fine but when I try to host my website from github the images do not load.

I do have the images saved in the same document as my index.html and style.css but in it's own folder. And the images are either png or jpeg.

I noticed some people say the caplocks do make a difference so I edited png and jpeg on github as PNG and JPEG. Still didn't make a difference.

Honestly I am very clueless in all this and find it hard in even asking a question that makes sense.

Could anyone please direct me to anywhere where I can learn github easily?

Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>The Ordinary</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Navigation Bar-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="brand-title">
                <img src="./Images/the-ordinary-logo.png" width="140px" height="50px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="location" src="./Images/location-icon.jpeg" title="Location" width="50px" height="50px"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="log" src="./Images/log-in-icon.jpeg" title="Login" width="50px" height="50px"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./Images/search-icon.jpeg" width="50px" title="Search" height="50px"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" title="Cart" width="60px" height="50px"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!--Banner-->

        <div class="banner">
            <a id="ordinary"><img class="banner-image" src="Images/hero-image.png" width="100%"/></a>
        </div>

        <!--Product Image-->

        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="#ordinary" href="ordinary">The Ordinary</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#products">Products</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="spacer">
                    <div class="cards">
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/cleanser.png" alt="Cleanser"/>
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/toner.png" alt="Toner"/>
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/hyaluronic-acid.png" alt="Hyaluronic Acid"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/moisturiser.png" alt="Moisturiser"/>
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/eye-cream.png" alt="Caffiene Eye Serum"/>
                            <img class="item" src="./Images/chemical-exfoliant.png" alt="Chemical Exfoliant"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Footer-->
        
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-container">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <h3>COMPANY</h3>
                    <p>About Us</p>
                    <p>Founder & Co-Founder</p>
                    <p>Team</p>
                    <p>Join Us</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-2">
                    <h3>CUSTOMER CARE</h3>
                    <p>Contact Us</p>
                    <p>FAQ</p>
                    <p>Disposal Instructions</p>
                    <p>Return Policy</p>
                    <p>Accessibility</p>
                    <p>Find Us</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="social-media">
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="copyright">
                <p>© THE ORDINARY INC. 2021. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
            </div>


        </footer>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: You are talking about GitHub pages, right?
 It would help, if could you post some of your HTML code here, especially the `<img>` tags. It seems like you have just used the wrong file path (absolute vs relative)

Comment: @Fabian Yes githib/github pages! Also included the code

Comment: Okay, you used relative paths (./), this should be right. Did you check if the image files are pushed to GitHub (are they visible when you open the repository view on GH)? Maybe you can also post a link to the page here

Comment: have you seen this [awner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141612/images-in-github-pages-and-relative-links)?

Comment: @fabian https://github.com/TamannaHoque/the-ordinary ok i'm not sure if you can view what I've linked. But I have a image file for the repository already created but not sure if that's what is meant by pushing the image file on to github. Thank you for helping